# Register CPTs using Dashicons for admin menu icon in WP 3.8

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-admin

WordPress 3.8 introduced in core the plugin MP6 that among other things use an iconic font called Dashicons to display fonts in the dashboard.

Now, is well know that [register_post_type](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type) has an argument `'menu_icon'` that allow to specify a custom icon for the CPT admin menu entry.

In my plugins/themes I often use that argument with my custom icon images that normally are dark because before 3.8 admin menu had a light background. With the default dark menu background in WP 3.8 my icons become almost invisible.

That aside, I think that use the new dashicons for my CPT will be cool.

After some research, I know I can just use the CSS from dashicons, something like

```
#menu-posts-mycpt div.wp-menu-image:before { content: "\f226"; }
```

However using both `'menu_icon'` argument of `register_post_type` **and** previous css will print both icons in WP 3.8 and one icon + a strange char in WP 3.8-, and without use `'menu_icon'` argument, on older versions the default icon is used.

I know I can conditionally add `'menu_icon'` in `register_post_type` for WP 3.8- versions and conditionally add previous css for WP 3.8+, but:

- that involves to add some code (2 conditional statements) for **every** CPT registered, so updating plugins/themes is quite an hard work
- it seems to me more a workaround than an elegant solution

So, questions are:

Is possible to use dashicons css for WP 3.8+ and use custom image set up via `'menu_icon'` param for previous versions in a "simpler" way that doesn't involve add 2 conditional for every CPT registered?

And, if so, is possible do that in some *automagic* way straight from `register_post_type` without any additional code?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After going through the rabbit hole and back, the answer is - **yes**, core does allow to easily use dashicons when registering post types and adding menu pages.

To use dashicon you need to pass its CSS class `dashicons-[name]` to `menu_icon` or `icon_url` in relevant places.

Classes available can be looked up in [`dashicons.css` in source](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/branches/3.8/src/wp-includes/css/dashicons.css#L34) or [Dashicons site](http://melchoyce.github.io/dashicons/) (click icon and look at the name for it on top).

**Alert!** 3.8 seems to have released with `dashicons-piechart` as example of the class in inline docs, which is wrong and won't work. Actual class for that icon in release is `dashicons-chart-pie`.

Comment: I've accepted this because it's the right way to do the thing. My plugin as the benefit to be better backward compatible (and I can fix to use class names instead of char) because if you put dashicons class in `menu_icon` you can't use image url for previous versions... but who cares of the past ? :)

Answer (score 4):

Easy: Just read the the relevant part of the `register_post_type()` phpDocBlock and then use the right argument for `menu_icon` :D

- Use the [dashicons](http://melchoyce.github.io/dashicons/) class. For e.g. `dashicon-groups`
- Pass a base64-encoded SVG using a data URI, which will be colored to match the color scheme. This should begin with `data:image/svg+xml;base64,`.
- Pass `'none'` to leave `div.wp-menu-image` empty, so an icon can be added via CSS.

Comment: *Dashicons class is what @Rarst says in his answer. *Using base64-encode can be useful, but imho not really straightforward, in addition `svg-painer.js`, the core js library used to handle color change, can be very time consuming if the icon is more "complex" then standard dashicons. *Third option (empty icon) is valid not only for WP 3.8+, but since a long time... and using css is something I want avoid (as per question). So +1 for putting all options together, but I think the accepted answer already aswer my question. P.S. happy to see that diamond near your name :)

Comment: @G.M. Interesting info about the `svg-painter.js` file. Didn't know it as I haven't tried yet.

Comment: Once I tried to use it in a a bit complex svg image (it was a simple building plant) to create a color change effect on mouse hover. I gave up and used another approach because of too latency.

Comment: @G.M. Thanks for that one. You should write a blog post about that :) I was searching and the only useful one I could find was the one [from Sven](http://hofmannsven.com/2013/laboratory/wordpress-dashicons/).

Answer (score 3):

I'm answering myself because today I asked myself the 2 questions I posted, and spent some time to find an answer. Once I found a solution, I want to share it, but any other solution is higly apprecciated and I'm ready to accept any solution that I found better than mine.
Edits and improvements to my solution are appreciated as well nay encouraged.

---

## Edit

After **Rarst** answer I've edited the code. Now function use standard dashicons classes, but **also** allow to specify an old style image url in `menu_icon` argument and a brand new dashicons class in the `menu_dashicon` argument.

---

### Workflow

First think I thought was that `register_post_type`, fires an action, `registered_post_type`, that pass to hooking functions the arguments passed to `register_post_type`, without filtering them, so is possible to creat custom arguments to that functions.

So I decided to pass the argument `'menu_dashicon'` to pass a custom dashicon.

After that I thought to create a class that listen to that argument, saving icon in a class variable. The same class can be responsible to

1. check the currnt version of WP, and if it is less then 3.8 do nothing
2. if version is 3.8+ loop the `$menu` array on proper hook and:
3. remove, if present, any custom images added via `'menu_icon'` and
4. add the inline style according the what is added via the `'menu_dashicon'` param

I create the code in a single file, in this way it can be easily included in any theme/plugin or even used as [MU plugin](http://codex.wordpress.org/Must_Use_Plugins) and after that one can just use the brand new `'menu_dashicon'` argument in every theme and/or plugin installed.

I've also added a minimal plugin header that allow to use it as a standalone plugin, but probably that's the less usefull way to use.

### How to use

Inside `register_post_type` just pass the `'menu_dashicon'` argument with the value of the dashicon class (**without** prefix 'dashicons-'):

```
$args = array(
  ...
  'menu_dashicon' => 'chart-pie', // dashicons will be used in WP 3.8+
  'menu_icon' => $url_of_the_icon // icon images will be used in WP 3.7.1 & previous
);

register_post_type('my_cpt', $args);
```

That's all. Get Dashicons icon class name from [its site](http://melchoyce.github.io/dashicons/).

So here the code:

```
<?php
/**
* Plugin Name: GM CPT Icon
*/
namespace GM;

class CptIcon {

  public static $cpt;
  
  public $css;
  
  static function registerIcon( $cpt, $icon ) {
    self::$cpt[$cpt] = $icon;
  }
  
  function init() {
    if ( $this->mp6() ) {
      \add_action('admin_menu', array($this, 'parseMenu') );
    }
  }
  
  function mp6() {
    return \version_compare( $GLOBALS['wp_version'],  '3.8', '>=' );
  }      
  
  function parseMenu() {
    if ( $this->mp6() && ! empty( self::$cpt ) )  {
      foreach ( $GLOBALS['menu'] as $i => $item ) {
        if  $item[1] === 'edit_posts' && (strpos($item[2], 'edit.php?post_type=') === 0)) {
          $this->menuItemClass($i, str_replace('edit.php?post_type=', '', $item[2]));
        }
      }
    }
  }
  
  function menuItemClass( $i, $type ) {
    if ( \in_array($type, \array_keys(self::$cpt), TRUE ) ) {
      $GLOBALS['menu'][$i][4] = str_replace('menu-icon-post', '', $GLOBALS['menu'][$i][4]);
      $GLOBALS['menu'][$i][6] = 'dashicons-' . self::$cpt[$type];
    }
  }

}

\add_action('plugins_loaded', function() {
  if ( \is_admin() && !( \defined('DOING_AJAX') && \DOING_AJAX  ) ) {
    $cpticon = new CptIcon;
    $cpticon->init();
  }
});

\add_action('registered_post_type', function( $post_type, $args ) {
  if ( isset($args->menu_dashicon) && ! empty($args->menu_dashicon) ) {
    CptIcon::registerIcon($post_type, $args->menu_dashicon);
  }
}, 10, 2);
```

It is also available as [**Gist**](https://gist.github.com/Giuseppe-Mazzapica/7951235)

---

[image: CPTs using dashicons]

Two CPTs: "Ideas" and "Gallery" using Dashicons. Note auto color change with different admin color schemes.

---

Answer (score 0):

I simply added this line to the code which registers the custom post type:

```
'menu_icon'    => 'dashicons-admin-users',
```

Here's the [full code](http://wpsites.net/web-design/add-custom-post-type/)

[image]

No need to add any CSS.

Comment: That's the exact thing that @Rarst says in his answer...

Comment: Rarst doesn't provide the line of code which needs adding to the code which creates the CPT or the full snippet which i have linked to. Also there's no need for CSS so my solution is more efficient.